# C++ template class with callback function

Tags: c++, class, templates, callback

Even though I read quite some about templates, this is the first time I try to actually use them. Thus my problem might be just a missing understanding of templates.

I have a class which is supposed to independently and periodically generate some data. When there is new data, it calls the parent via callback function and sends the data. The class is supposed to be portable, thus the templated parent.

But if I use the template on my data class, I have to drag the template with me into every function and it just felt unnecessary complex for just being able to call one function. So I created a small callback class in a global namespace, which I wanted to use as a interface.

```
namespace wrapper
{
    //Callback class
    template<typename ParentClass>
    class Data_Callback
    {
    public:
        ParentClass* m_parent = nullptr;
        Data_Callback<ParentClass>(ParentClass* parent)
        {
            m_parent = parent;
        };

        void DoCallback(DataClass* data)
        {
            if (m_parent)
                m_parent->callback_func(*data);
        }
    };

    //global object I want to use for callback
    template<typename ParentClass>
    std::unique_ptr<Data_Callback<ParentClass>> m_parentCallback;

    template<typename ParentClass>
    PatientenErkennung GetNewDataClass(ParentClass* parent)
    {
        m_parentCallback = std::make_unique<Data_Callback<ParentClass>>(parent);

        std::shared_ptr<DataClass> obj =  std::make_shared<DataClass>();
        return obj;
    };
}
```

I can then call my global "GetNewDataClass" function like this from my parent class:

```
m_data = wrapper::GetNewDataClass(this);
```

But when I want to call the callback from the DataClass, the template gets in the way:

```
wrapper::m_parentCallback<I_DONT_HAVE_THIS>->DoCallback(data);
```

I can't call that global object, without knowing the parent class, can I? Thus the callback can only be initialized from the Data_Callback class, but that class doesn't contain the data.

How do you solve this? Inheritance maybe? Or is the design per se not usable like this?
As I said before, I want to avoid to have my larger DataClass drag a template around DataClass, though this would work...

Comment: What you currently have is a different global object for every type of parent class. Is that what you want conceptually, or did you want exactly one global callback variable that should be used by everything?

Comment: If you use 'inheritance' – well, in this context, better term is 'polymorphism', then you wouldn't need the wrapper any more. You'd design a common interface for all types of parent classes and each separate type would then inherit from that common base. If that fit's your needs, though, depends on how you intend to use those parents...

Comment: @MaxLanghof In my case it is actually the same, because there will only ever be one instance of DataClass and it is initialized together with the callback. You are right, though: it was meant to be only one global object.

Comment: @Aconcagua I just used the wrapper as some sort of work around. I am not dependend on it. There will only ever be one parent class matching one DataClass object and I need that parent object only for the callback function.
A pointer to the member callback function would also work, but I decided that that approach is neither better nor easier in c++.
Do you have an example how the parent pointer could be inherited, without having an template in my DataClass?

Comment: `struct Base { virtual ~Base() { }; virtual void f() = 0; }; struct Derived : Base { void f() override { } }; Base* b = new Derived(); b->f();` – due to f being virtual, the variant of the most derived class available will be called, in given example, `Derived::f`, even though the pointer is of type `Base`.

Comment: @Aconcagua I see that this approach would be easier, but then it would be up to the developer to write a useable class. My goal was to create a ready to use class with a callback function. I solved that by now with std::function storing a lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need type erasure, which you could roll by hand. But the standard already provides a universal interface for functions (including callbacks) of any kind: `std::function` (which internally does the type erasure you'd need here).

```
namespace wrapper
{
    //global object I want to use for callback
    std::function<void(DataClass&)> m_parentCallback;

    template<typename ParentClass>
    auto GetNewDataClass(ParentClass* parent)
    {
        m_parentCallback = [parent](DataClass& dc){ parent->callback_func(dc); };

        std::shared_ptr<DataClass> obj =  std::make_shared<DataClass>();
        return obj;
    };
}
```

`m_parentCallback` is declared as a `std::function` that takes a `DataClass` reference and returns nothing. We initialize it in `GetNewDataClass` with a lambda which captures the value of the `parent` pointer and calls `callback_func` on that pointer with the `DataClass` instance passed to it.

(You could actually skip the lambda here and just write

```
 m_parentCallback = parent->callback_func;
```

but lambdas are more flexible and thus "canonically" used for this. Plus you will probably get better error messages if `parent` doesn't have a `callback_func`.)

To use it, just call it like a function:

```
wrapper::m_parentCallback(data);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nUG9Bx

You probably are aware, but I would strongly discourage using global variables in so tightly linked ways. For now (and possibly for the "lifetime" of your project) it'll work fine, but this really does not scale. `wrapper` could probably be a class in itself.

Comment: Thank you. Except for several linker errors due to multiple definition this is working fine. 
To the comment you added: I thought that having a callback function should be quite common, at least since worker threads appeared. So there must be a common/better way already? I wanted to solve my problem but I am also interested in how this should have been done.

Comment: The problem is not with the concept of a callback function itself, but with the assumption that there is only one "customer" using the callback function. If you had two different parent class instances that both should receive (different) callbacks from (different) data generators, your global variable approach would fall apart. Don't worry too much about it for now, but be wary of when you might be hurting yourself with the global variable usages.